# How to process a string?

Tags: c++, string, counting

The first line of input will be 2 integers, h and w, which is the height(h) and width(w) of the rectangular area of sky you will be counting stars from. You may assume their values are below 1000.

The following h lines will have w characters per line, either x (Clear Sky) or * (star).

Sample Input

```
5 5
```

```
x***x
xxx*x
x*xxx
xxx*x
*xxxx
```

Sample output

> 7

How can I process the string?

Comment: This looks like homework to me. In any case here are some helpful resources: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdstring-class-in-c/ https://cal-linux.com/tutorials/conditionals.html https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operators-c-c/

Comment: Hello to stack overflow (SO). 
We here at SO are eager to help you, but please play along our rules, to make it easier for us. 
Consider reading through the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and 
taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Especially consider reading through 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable to count the stars with an appropriate data type.

Iterate (loop) over the string to check each character for equality with `'*'`. If this is the case then increment your star counter.

Width and height are not required. If you want to constrain a larger field to the width and height provided, you can use a column (character# in a line) and a row (line#) counter and keep track where in the file you are.
After each character in your string increment (add 1) your column counter. After each line ('\n'-character denotes a new line) increment your row counter and reset the column counter. if your current column or row exceed the provided width or height, then ignore any `'*'`-characters until you are within bounds again or the string ends.

I leave the actual code for you as an excercise.

Helpful links:

- [Strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdstring-class-in-c/)
- [Operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operators-c-c/)
- [Conditionals](https://cal-linux.com/tutorials/conditionals.html)

If you have trouble with the input part, you should consider looking elsewhere than stackoverflow.